# Optional chaining sonar bug

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

Sonar throws me a major bug:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

For that syntax:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.state?.complete();
}
```

Why a conditional chaining is a bug for the function call?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that's a known issue and should be fixed in a more recent version: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/optional-chaining-in-typescript-is-reported-as-an-expression/21265/5